# Unhandled Exception in nvoglv32.dll - Calling imageStore in a for loop

Tags: glsl, compute-shader

I am attempting to fill an image3D using a for loop in my compute shader.

The following three lines of code are valid when outside a for loop, since the program will run and give expected results:

```
position = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xyz);
colour = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
imageStore(visualTexture, position, colour); //visualTexture being an empty image3D 
//fed into the shader
```

However, when placed in a for loop, an unhandled exception in `nvoglv32.dll` is thrown, and fatal program exit requested. Originally I thought that this might be due to me attempting to write to the same position multiple times, but of course that doesn't apply with this code because the Global Invocation ID is going to be unique to each iteration, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so very stupid. The reason why it wasn't working was that my for loop looked like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; i++)
```

i was a variable in the previous for loop, which no longer exists, and as such, the program breaks.